# Can't Update Access database File From C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, insert-update

I try to learn some coding with Visual C#. I create a form for add and update Access database.

I can successfully add to Access file but I can't update them.

I write a code similar below by some search in internet but I get this error:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

My code is:

```
public partial class form1 : Form
{
   private OleDbConnection con;

   private void btnUpDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            string FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            string Family = txtFamily.Text;
            string City = txtCity.Text;
            string approve = txtapprove.Text;
            string OfficeNumber = txtOfficeNumber.Text;
            string OfficialDossier = txtOfficialDossier.Text;
            string Department = txtDepartment.Text;
            string Organization = txtOrganization.Text;

            OleDbConnection oleDBConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Data Source=F:\\Database.accdb");
            string query = "UPDATE Sheet1 SET FirstName=@FirstName, Family=@Family, City=@City, approve=@approve, OfficeNumber=@OfficeNumber, OfficialDossier=@OfficialDossier, Department=@Department, Organization=@Organization WHERE OfficeNumber=@OfficeNumber";

            //string query = "UPDATE aspnet_Users SET FirstName=@FirstName, Family=@Family,  City=@City, approve=@approve, OfficeNumber=@OfficeNumber, OfficialDossier=@OfficialDossier, Department=@Department WHERE OfficeNumber=@OfficeNumber";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, oleDBConn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficeNumber", OfficeNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficialDossier", OfficialDossier);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Family", Family);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", City);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@approve", approve);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", Department);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Organization", Organization);

            try
            {
                con.Open();

                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (result > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Sorry!");
            }
            catch (OleDbException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is a problem!");
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Where I have mistake? I Don't use of DataSet and DataAdapter. Is problem from there?

I'm using VS 2010

Answer (score 4):

**Problem 1:** You have not Opened the Connection object `oleDBConn` which was assigned to the `OleDbCommand` Object.

You have assigned `oleDBConn` to OleDbCommand  object as below:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, oleDBConn);//here you have assigned oleDbConn
```

but you have opened different ConnectionObject `con` as below:

```
con.Open();
```

**Solution 1:**

Replace This: You should always Open the `OleDbConnection` (oleDBConn) Object which was assigned to the `OleDbCOmmand` Object.

```
 con.Open();
```

With This:

```
oleDBConn.Open();
```

**Problem 2:** You have created an Extra connection object `con` (on top of your `btnUpDate_Click` function) and by mistake you are working with the same.(Opening  and closing the wrong connection object instead of proper one)

**Solution 2:** Remove the extra connection object created on top of `btnUpDate_Click` function and replace all `con` occurences with `oleDBConn`.

**Complete Code:**

```
try
{
oleDBConn.Open();

int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (result > 0)
MessageBox.Show("Success!");
else
MessageBox.Show("Sorry!");
}
catch (OleDbException ex)
{
MessageBox.Show("There is a problem!"+ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
oleDBConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: @user3346389: u mean it is saying `sorry` always?

Comment: Yes! I chang it correctly. I can't assume what is wrong!

Comment: @user3346389:can you debug and see wthat is error and exception message?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't debug it! still I don't arrive to debug chapter :)

Comment: Because I can add new row in database, I think error must be of declared string! But I'm not professional! :)

Comment: @user3346389: dear pleae change your catch block as shown in my edited answer and let me know what it returns.

Comment: Nothing! Just Sorry Message!